# Code for page to display correctly on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

I have created a new website and everything's fine on my PC and Mac but when I go to my mobile phone, I see a grey thick vertical stripe at the right side of the screen.

I have tried some things from the Internet, but nothing worked for me. I appreciate any other help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please supply the offending code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add this line in HEAD tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

I think, thick stripe is border and add this code to your css file (at the beginning)

```
* {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Also, you can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for responsive design